# Flutter Firebase Remote Config No virtual method isDeveloperModeEnabled()Z in class .../FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-remote-config

I have recently upgraded all my firebase libraries in my Flutter project. After that I'm getting the message:

> /flutter (27126): [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(43)] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method isDeveloperModeEnabled()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings' appears in /data/app/package_name-1UBO7FEPHLsC2_eb7itJLA==/base.apk!classes3.dex)

After that my app crashes with the error:

> [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(942)] Check failed: CheckException(env).

Currently I'm using:

> firebase_remote_config: ^0.4.0+2

> firebase_core: 0.5.0+1

My dependencies in the android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:7.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Finally solved ..

Okey not only changing this line

```
properties.put("inDebugMode", firebaseRemoteConfigInfo.getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled());
```

to

```
properties.put("inDebugMode", false);
```

& changing this

```
FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings settings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().setDeveloperModeEnabled(debugMode).build();
firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(settings);
```

to

```
FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings settings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder().build();
firebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(settings);
```

You need also to change this

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaults(defaults);
```

to

```
FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaultsAsync(defaults);
```

Still its an annoying issue and should be solved asap

Comment: Yeah, I actually forgot about this additional steps I've done, here is +1 for your effort posting it here

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in plugin, see github issue for details:
https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4035

Workaround: just add

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom')
```

To your `build.gradle`

Comment: How exactly did you find MethodCallHandler file ? i been looking for it the whole day on my mac with no luck

Comment: @user4415205 go to folder, where you installed flutter, here is hidden folder `.pub-cache`. Or if you are using IntelliJ you can easily find it under `External Libraries -> Flutter Plugins` in project navigator

Comment: Thank you, i found it and i did the update but same issue, is there any additional steps to this change?

Comment: @DimaRostopira I don't have the `MethodCallHandler.java` file directly inside the hidden `.pub-cache` folder. If I then go to the `hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_remote_config-0.4.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/firebase/firebaseremoteconfig` folder I found a `MethodCallHandlerImpl.java` file. It doesn't have the suggested `FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().setDefaults(defaults);` to change.. Is it the wrong file?

Comment: @Vincenzo try adding `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom')` to your build gradle

Comment: @DimaRostopira indeed, changing `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')` to `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom')` worked, without touching the java file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code in your android app's build gradle if it is set:

```
rootProject.ext {
    set('FlutterFire', [
            FirebaseSDKVersion: '26.1.1'
    ])
}
```